# How to validate Google reCaptcha v2 using phalcon/volt forms?

Tags: php, recaptcha, phalcon, volt

How do you validate the new Google reCaptcha using volt and phalcon techniques?

(Just wanted to share what I did to make it work, see answer below, hope it helps...)

Answer (score 3):

## What you will need

- A Validator (RecaptchaValidator in this case)
- `Form` implementation
- `Controller` implementation (actually no changes needed here, but for completeness...)
- `View` implementation
- (optional) Config entries for your recaptcha keys and url (nicer/cleaner this way)
- (optional) A recaptcha element for automatic rendering (if you prefer the render method)

## The Validator

The validator is the most crucial part of this, all other things are rather intuitive ...

```
use \Phalcon\Validation\Validator;
use \Phalcon\Validation\ValidatorInterface;
use \Phalcon\Validation\Message;

class RecaptchaValidator extends Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{
    public function validate(\Phalcon\Validation $validation, $attribute) 
    {
        if (!$this->isValid($validation)) {
            $message = $this->getOption('message');
            if ($message) { // Add the custom message defined in the "Form" class
                $validation->appendMessage(new Message($message, $attribute, 'Recaptcha'));
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /********************************************
     *  isValid - Return Values
     *  =======================
     *  true .... Ok
     *  false ... Not Ok
     *  null .... Error
     */
    public function isValid($validation) 
    {
        try {
            $config = $validation->config->recaptcha; // not needed if you don't use a config
            $value =  $validation->getValue('g-recaptcha-response');
            $ip    =  $validation->request->getClientAddress();

            $url = $config->verifyUrl; // or 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'; without config
            $data = ['secret'   => $config->secretKey, // or your secret key directly without using the config
                     'response' => $value,
                     'remoteip' => $ip,
                    ];

            // Prepare POST request
            $options = [
                'http' => [
                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'content' => http_build_query($data),
                ],
            ];

            // Make POST request and evaluate the response
            $context  = stream_context_create($options);
            $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
            return json_decode($result)->success;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

## Form (class) implementation

```
class SignupForm extends Form
{
    public function initialize($entity = null, $options = null) 
    {
        // Name (just as an example of other form fields)
        $name = new Text('name');
        $name->setLabel('Username');
        $name->addValidators(array(
            new PresenceOf(array(
                'message' => 'Please enter your name'
            ))
        ));
        $this->add($name);

        // Google Recaptcha v2
        $recaptcha = new Check('recaptcha');
        $recaptcha->addValidator(new RecaptchaValidator([
            'message' => 'Please confirm that you are human'
        ]));
        $this->add($recaptcha);

        // Other form fields...
}
```

## Controller implementation

Even though the controller is the same as with every other form, for completeness sake here an example...

```
class SessionController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function signupAction()
    {
        $form = new SignupForm();
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($this->request->getPost()) != false) 
            {
                // Add user to database, do other checks, etc.
                // ...
            }
        }

        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
}
```

## View implementation

For the view you can either just put the html there or let it be rendered by the engine. If you want it rendered instead (with e.g. `{{ form.render('recaptcha') }}`), you will have to also create an `Recaptcha` Element instead of using one of the defaults (see last point in this answer for that).

```
...

{{ form('class':'signupForm') }}
<fieldset>

    <div>{{ form.label('name') }}</div>
        {{ form.render('name') }}
        {{ form.messages('name') }}

    <!-- other elements here -->        
    <!-- ...                 -->

    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{ this.config.recaptcha.publicKey }}"></div>
    {{ form.messages('recaptcha') }}
```

If you don't wanna use a config for your public key (next section), just set the value of the data-sitekey to your personal (Google reCaptcha) public key.

Also don't forget to include the script (`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`) somewhere (e.g. in your html head section).

## (Optional) Config

If you wanna use the config to store your recaptcha keys, also add the following to your `config/config.php` ...

```
// config/config.php

return new \Phalcon\Config([

    'application' => [
        'controllersDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/controllers/',
        'modelsDir'      => __DIR__ . '/../../app/models/',
        'formsDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/forms/',
        'viewsDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/views/',
        'pluginsDir'     => __DIR__ . '/../../app/plugins/',
        'libraryDir'     => __DIR__ . '/../../app/library/',
        'cacheDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/cache/',
        'baseUri'        => '/',
    ],

    // other configs here
    // ...

    'recaptcha' => [
        'publicKey' => 'your public key',
        'secretKey' => 'your private key',
        'verifyUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    ],
]);
```

To be able to access the config in your view, you might also need to add `$di->set('config', $config);` to your dependency injector (typically within `config/services.php`).

## (Optional) Recaptcha Element

If you want your recaptcha to be rendered for you (instead of you putting the `div` directly in the view), you will need a separate `\Phalcon\Forms\Element\` ...

```
class Recaptcha extends \Phalcon\Forms\Element
{
    public function render($attributes = null) {
        return '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="'
            .$this->config->recaptcha->publicKey
            .'"></div>';
    }
}
```

You will also have to change your `Form` accordingly:

```
// ...
$recaptcha = new Recaptcha('recaptcha');
$recaptcha->addValidator(new RecaptchaValidator([
    'message' => '...'
]));
// ...
```

And finally also your `View`:

```
{{ form.render('recaptcha') }}
```